# In Django Restframework, how to create user model with profile model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to create a User with a Profile on Serializer's create method.
Expected input is (name, email, and password).
email and password will be used to create a User instance and the name and user instance itself will be used to create a Profile instance.

In UserRegisterSerializer, the model is User and I defined an additional field 'name' since it is not a field of the User model.
in create method, the name is popped from validated data, and the user is created with email and password.
the profile is created with the user and name.

When I test for creating a user, it raises an error message
'AttributeError at /api/users/register/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `UserRegisterSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Users` instance.
The original exception text was: 'Users' object has no attribute 'name'.'

I don't understand it since I didn't attempt to get a value for the field name.

How should I fix it? What is my mistake?

Views.py

class UserRegisterAPIView(CreateAPIView):
queryset = User.objects.all()
serializer_class = UserRegisterSerializer

Models.py

Users : customized user that has id, email, password etc fields.

Profiles : 1 to 1 linked with Users. It has user, name, etc fields.

Serializers.py

```
User = get_user_model() 

        
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profiles
        fields = '__all__'


class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'password')
        
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())],
        )
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True,
        required=True,
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        validators=[validate_password],
        )

        

    def create(self, validated_data):
        name = validated_data.pop('name')
        
        
        #create a new user with validated data
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['email'],
            )
        
        #Set the hashed password for the user and save profile object
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        
        
        #create a new profile object linked to the user
        profile = Profiles.objects.create(
            user=user,
            name=name
            )
        profile.save()

        
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

The final part of your error message mentions that the  `'Users' object has no attribute 'name'.`

In your serializer code, you have added the additional field. But since its still a model serializer, your model also needs to have the field.
You can add a new field into your default User model, using the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) as reference.
The rest of your code should function properly once you include the `name` in your `User` model.

Comment: So, is there no way to do so without modifying model? I am using customized User.